# Link not clickable due to menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have inserted below code which contains menu at right side with hover effect. also i have some content with link. But that link not clickable due to menu.

```css
.menubar{position: fixed;right:0;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);-o-transform: translateY(-50%);-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);overflow: hidden;z-index: 1;}
    .menu{width: auto;height: 40px;line-height: 40px;padding: 0 15px;transform: translateX(85%);-webkit-transform: translateX(85%);-o-transform: translateX(85%);-moz-transform: translateX(85%);transition: all 0.5s ease;margin: 10px auto;border-radius: 5px;cursor: pointer;}
    .menu a{color: #fff;}
    .menu a:hover{color: #fff;opacity:1;}
    .menu a i{margin-right: 10px;}
    .menu:hover{transform: translateX(0%);-webkit-transform: translateX(0%);-o-transform: translateX(0%);-moz-transform: translateX(0%);}
    .blue-bkg{background: #38488e;}
    .homemenu-blue-bkg{background: #38488e;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
    <div class="menubar hidden-xs">
     <div class="menu homemenu-blue-bkg" data-dept="blue"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="srt"><a href="#"><i class="icon-srt"></i>Share Registry & Transfer</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="payroll"><a href="#"><i class="icon-pp"></i>Payroll Processing</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="trust"><a href="#"><i class="icon-ta"></i>Trust Administration</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="rms"><a href="#"><i class="icon-rms"></i>Record Management Services</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="dsc"><a href="#"><i class="icon-dsc"></i>Digital Signature Certification</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="cfdm"><a href="#"><i class="icon-cfdm"></i>Corporate FD Management</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p><p>, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived</p><p> not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum  Aldus PageMaker including.
    <a href="click here">More</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I want hover effect of menu as well as link should clickable. How can i achieve this.

Comment: add link instead of # then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaked it a bit. Check it out. You may consider adding the vendor-prefixes to the `transform`s if you want.

- Added `#` for `click here` in `href` attribute of the hyperlink at the bottom.
- Shifted the whole `.menubar` to 85% right (out of the canvas).
- Asked `.menu` to translate 85% to the left when hovered.

```css
    .menubar{position: fixed;right:0;top: 50%;transform: translate(85%,-50%);z-index: 1;}
    .menu{width: auto;height: 40px;line-height: 40px;padding: 0 15px;transition: all 0.5s ease;margin: 10px auto;border-radius: 5px;cursor: pointer;}
    .menu a{color: #fff;}
    .menu a:hover{color: #fff;opacity:1;}
    .menu a i{margin-right: 10px;}
    .menu:hover{transform: translateX(-85%);}
    .blue-bkg{background: #38488e;}
    .homemenu-blue-bkg{background: #38488e;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
    <div class="menubar hidden-xs">
     <div class="menu homemenu-blue-bkg" data-dept="blue"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="srt"><a href="#"><i class="icon-srt"></i>Share Registry & Transfer</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="payroll"><a href="#"><i class="icon-pp"></i>Payroll Processing</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="trust"><a href="#"><i class="icon-ta"></i>Trust Administration</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="rms"><a href="#"><i class="icon-rms"></i>Record Management Services</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="dsc"><a href="#"><i class="icon-dsc"></i>Digital Signature Certification</a></div>
     <div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="cfdm"><a href="#"><i class="icon-cfdm"></i>Corporate FD Management</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p><p>, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived</p><p> not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum  Aldus PageMaker including.
    <a href="#">More</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. I hope this help's

```
<a href="http://www.breedeal.com" target="_blank">More</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">More</a>
```

and add css like this

```
a:hover{ color: black; }
```

Comment: As i said, link is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You have just haven't closed your tags correctly.

```
<p><a href="click here">More</p></a>

<!-- Should be -->

<p><a href="click here">More</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a z-index as follows:

Add a class to the a element

```
 <a href="click here" class="text-link">More</a></p>
```

And add this markup to it

```
.text-link {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to click a menu item instead of `a href` link.

Then wrap your anchor tag outside the menu item div

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" ><div class="menu homemenu-blue-bkg" data-dept="blue"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</div></a>
```

Otherwise just click on content (Share Registry & Transfer) and your link will work

```
<div class="menu blue-bkg" data-dept="srt"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><i class="icon-srt"></i>Share Registry & Transfer</a></div>
```

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cceh7hswi0WIMaQLZaer?p=preview)